# Mysql query select case when true insert

Tags: mysql, select, insert, case

### Does anybody know how to do this syntax below in mysql?

Without Stored Procedure, and in single query only

---

```
SELECT CASE
 WHEN COUNT(v.value) = 0 THEN (
  INSERT INTO tbl_v (fid, uid, VALUE)
  SELECT fid, 1 AS uid, 'xxxxxx' AS VALUE FROM tbl_f
  WHERE category = 'categoryname' AND NAME = 'somevalue'
 )WHEN v.value <> 'test' THEN (
  'update syntax here' /* will be similar like insert statement above */
 )ELSE (
  v.value
 )END
FROM shared_tbl_f f
INNER JOIN tbl_v v ON f.fid = v.fid
WHERE v.uid = 1 AND f.category = 'categoryname' AND f.name = 'somevalue'
```

---

Note:

There's no primary key on `tbl_v`
the unique reference for `tbl_v` is only a combination from column fid and column uid.

Because `tbl_v` is a mapping table (there's no primary key there) - fid and uid is a foreign key from another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause with your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_v (fid, uid, VALUE)
  SELECT fid, 1 AS uid, 'xxxxxx' AS VALUE FROM tbl_f
  WHERE category = 'categoryname' AND NAME = 'somevalue'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  value = ?;
```

To get this to work their needs to be either a primary key or unique index on a column. A duplicate value will then start the update part of the statement.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

Comment: thanks for the response, but
is this method still possible, if the unique key is a combination from column fid and column uid? because tbl_v is a mapping table (there's no primary key there) - fid and uid is a foreign key from another table

Comment: It sounds like there should be a composite primary key on tbl_v of (fid, uid). You could use the following to add one. `ALTER TABLE tbl_v ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (fid, uid);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, sorry. You have to do this in a stored procedure or in your applicationlogic.

Comment: is it? previously it's used 2 queries, but I think it's more optimal if using 1 query in one go rather than multiple query called from application logic